# serialise a spring cache to assist with testing

Tags: java, spring, caching

I want to do some unit tests with a spring cache.
I want to populate the cache with a `GET` request. Then I serialize the entire cache to disk. So, when I build the project, the cache will be put in state that I could trip back between tests, like the database, when I serialize.

I could populate this by hand, but this could mean I could 'cache' the cache as it were in a broad stroke.

Comment: I dont see a question here? What exactly is your problem/what you want to do.

Comment: I want to take this : https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/ and serialise whatever is in the cache to disk. I want to essentially give the cache a fixture, so I can have the cache "prepopulated" whereever i build my project.